# Remove Federation Errors in SAML 2.0 and ADFS 3.0

Tags: saml-2.0, centos7, shibboleth, adfs3.0

I am setting up ADFS 3.0 and SAML 2.0 using Shibboleth as a Service Provider (SP). I have successfully imported the certificates to ADFS. The ADFS Claims Provider (or ADFS IDP) login page works, because the user is redirected to:

```
https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST`
```

after logging in to:

```
https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon
```

However, whenever I run this command:

```
systemctl restart shibd && systemctl restart httpd
```

I get the following errors:

```
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 2732, message: grammar not found for namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 2732, message: attribute 'ServiceDisplayName' is not declared for element 'RoleDescriptor'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 3923, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ClaimTypesRequested'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 24961, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:TargetScopes'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 25333, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ApplicationServiceEndpoint'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 25536, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 25724, message: element 'fed:ClaimTypesRequested' is not allowed for content model '(Signature?,Extensions?,KeyDescriptor*,Organization?,ContactPerson*)'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26099, message: grammar not found for namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26099, message: attribute 'ServiceDisplayName' is not declared for element 'RoleDescriptor'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 27277, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:TokenTypesOffered'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 27444, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ClaimTypesOffered'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 48496, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 49192, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 49380, message: element 'fed:TokenTypesOffered' is not allowed for content model '(Signature?,Extensions?,KeyDescriptor*,Organization?,ContactPerson*)'
2016-11-09 16:54:36 ERROR OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : error while loading resource (https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
2016-11-09 16:54:36 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : adjusted reload interval to 600 seconds
2016-11-09 16:54:36 CRIT Shibboleth.Application : error initializing MetadataProvider: XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
```

Here's my shibboleth.xml configuration

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML::2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    clockSkew="180">


    <!-- ADFS Extension -->
    <OutOfProcess>
        <Extensions>
            <Library path="/usr/lib64/shibboleth/adfs.so" fatal="true"/>
        </Extensions>
    </OutOfProcess>
    <InProcess logger="native.log" checkSpoofing="true">
        <Extensions>
            <Library path="/usr/lib64/shibboleth/adfs-lite.so" fatal="true"/>
        </Extensions>
    </InProcess>
    <RequestMapper type="Native"
        sessionError="/var/log/shibboleth/session_error.log"
        metadataError="/var/log/shibboleth/metadata_error.log"
        accessError="/var/log/shibboleth/access_error.log"
        sslError="/var/log/shibboleth/ssl_error.log">
        <RequestMap applicationId="default">
            <Host name="c-app01">
                <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
            </Host>
        </RequestMap>
    </RequestMapper>

    <!-- The ApplicationDefaults element is where most of Shibboleth's SAML bits are defined. -->
    <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://c-app01.contoso.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata.xml"
            REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id">
        <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem"
                 checkAddress="false" handlerSSL="true" cookieProps="https">
            <!-- Putting another SSO here will make shibd fail. There should only be one SSO. -->
            <SSO>
                SAML2 SAML1 ADFS
            </SSO>
            <!-- SAML and local-only logout. -->
            <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
            <!-- Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. -->
            <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata.xml" signing="false"/>
            <!-- Status reporting service. -->
            <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
            <!-- Session diagnostic service. -->
            <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>
            <!-- JSON feed of discovery information. -->
            <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
        </Sessions>
        <Errors supportContact="root@localhost"
            helpLocation="/about.html"
            styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>
        <!-- Example of remotely supplied batch of signed metadata. -->


        <!-- using validate="true" will give errors in Federationmetadata.xml-->
        <MetadataProvider type="XML" validate="true"
            uri="https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
            reloadInterval="3600">
          <DiscoveryFilter type="Blacklist" matcher="EntityAttributes" trimTags="true"
            attributeName="http://macedir.org/entity-category"
            attributeNameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
            attributeValue="http://refeds.org/category/hide-from-discovery" />
        </MetadataProvider>
        <!-- Example of locally maintained metadata. -->
        <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="attribute-map.xml"/>
        <!-- Use a SAML query if no attributes are supplied during SSO. -->
        <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
        <!-- Default filtering policy for recognized attributes, lets other data pass. -->
        <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
        <!-- Simple file-based resolver for using a single keypair. -->
        <CredentialResolver type="File" key="c-app01.contoso.com.key" certificate="c-app01.contoso.com.pem"/>
    </ApplicationDefaults>


    <!-- Policies that determine how to process and authenticate runtime messages. -->
    <SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>


    <!-- Low-level configuration about protocols and bindings available for use. -->
    <ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>


</SPConfig>
```

Here's my apache configuration:

```
LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so

ShibCompatValidUser Off

<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  SetHandler shib
  AuthType None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

So, my question is... how do I configure the Service Provider to get the ClaimTypesOffered, etc. (in the error) to remove the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configure SP**

So, the solution was to use `validate="false"` in the `MetadataProvider` tag inside `shibboleth2.xml`

**Configure IDP**

The email address and phone number should be filled out in ADFS.

This configuration is located in: `AD FS Management > Service (right click) > Service Federation Properties > Organization`

**Execution**

After the steps above, I went to the SP, and was able to redirect to the IDP Login page when using the link:

`https://c-app01.contoso.com/Shibboleth.sso/Login?entityID=https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata.xml/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml?target=https://c-app01.contoso.com/secure`

It successfully redirect back to the `target` after IDP login.

**Other things to note:**

Make sure that the Federation Service Identifier is using the `Metadata` located in:

`AD FS Management > Service (right click) > Service Federation Properties > General`

In my case, it is `https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`